AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'
In DataFrame df, I am having index column as Timestamp in it some values are in format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f and other values in format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S due to which I am facing issue in Sorting the index df =df.sort_index() as well and Data Fomat it also different.
My Code:
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame with mixed datetime formats in the index
data = {
    'final_lowerband': [None, None, None, 6698.0, 6698.0, 6698.0],
    'final_upperband': [None, None, None, None, None, None],
}
index = [
    '2024-07-12 20:38:59.667000',
    '2024-07-12 19:38:59.957000',
    '2024-07-12 19:36:59.897000',
    '2024-07-12 19:13:59.870000',
    '2024-07-12 18:15:59',
    '2024-07-12 21:35:00',
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

# Convert index to DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# Convert index to desired format
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Display the DataFrame with the updated index format
print(df)

ERROR 1 for Line: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
ValueError: time data "2024-07-12 18:15:59" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", at position 4. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

ERROR 2 From Line: df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'

When Tried Sorting Index , without `strfdatetime getting error.
ERROR 3: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'
df = df.sort_index()

Expected Output:
Timestamp             final_lowerband   final_upperband
2024-07-12 18:15:59         6698.0  NaN
2024-07-12 19:13:59         6698.0  NaN     
2024-07-12 19:36:59          NaN    NaN
2024-07-12 19:38:59          NaN    NaN
2024-07-12 20:38:59          NaN    NaN
2024-07-12 21:35:00         6698.0  NaN


Your data dict contains more values than you have indices (not directly related, but it will cause issues)

This code doesn't run. ValueError: Length of values (8) does not match length of index (6). Please provide a [mre] with working code. For specific tips, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples

If I remove data values to match the output, then pd.to_datetime(df.index) fails: ValueError: time data "2024-07-12 18:15:59" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", at position 4. [...]. This might be version-specific; what version are you using?

What's crudeoilm? Your dataframe is called df.

Also, please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. You might want to ask something like "Why are some of my index values still str after to_datetime()?" though the problem should be clearer once you make a [mre] :)

all corrected !!!

From Pandas 2.0 above you can pass mixed to format parameter.
And also if you don't care about .f part as it seems from your output, you don't need that in strftime. With that:
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='mixed', dayfirst=False).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.sort_index()


It'd be better to keep the index as datetime so that you can still, e.g. resample. To truncate fractional seconds, use df.index.floor('S'). Ref: How to remove seconds from datetime?
